# Is it possible to plot multidimensional points in parallel aligned axes with python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, plot, coordinate-systems

I want to plot multidimensional points in a graph. To do so, I want each axis lined up in parallel. So every point becomes a line in this plot. Maybe there is also a special name for this type of graphs/plots? In the figure below, I have sketched a picture of such a plot with exemplarily 4 axes and the point (5, 60, -10, 7.5). It would be fantastic if the axes are scalable seperately.
Does anybody know a plot-package in python which is capable to plot in this way, and how to do it in that library?

[image: Desired plot of parallel aligned coordinate axes.]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a straightforward way to do that.

However, I can recommend using Radar Plots, it shows exactly the information you want to show:

https://williamhuster.com/radar-chart-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I already thought about radar plots, but it might be problematic if the dimensions goes up to a few hundret. So it might be better to have a plot which is scrollable. On the other hand I can see everything in one picture using radar plots.